# Создать приложение для чтения книг под android на Java

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм - куда двигаться, чтобы создать приложение для чтения книг под android. Может быть какая-нибудь готовая библиотека есть? Нужно интегрировать читалку в существующее приложение.

Comment: Есть книга "Mark Murphy - The Busy Coder's Guide to Android", там как раз и описывается подробно создание книги. На английском. Но гугл переводчик вполне поможет.

Comment: если нужно готовое - идете на гитхаб, ищете какой то reader под android, редактируйте код под себя